# Where should I put background processes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process, rufus-scheduler

I'm building a Rails project that has a cron-type job that I'm managing with Rufus Scheduler. I have two questions about how to set this up appropriately in Rails:

1. Where's the best place to put the job's code?
2. Where should I place the Rufus code to schedule the job? How should I kick it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To control the scheduler I would create a `config/initializers/task_scheduler.rb`:

```
task_scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new  

task_scheduler.every("1m") do  
   Something.to_do! # Do something every minute! 
end
```

Now for the `Something.to_do` code, that sort of depends on what it does. Perhaps it is a data model and it should go in the `app/models` directory, but if it is something more generic you might want to place it in `lib/`. If you wind up with a number of scheduled tasks you might want to create a `app/scheduled_tasks` directory, but that might be overkill for just one file.

Comment: Though this solution is simple one, there will be issues when you deploy your rails app in multiprocess server like unicorn or passenger, your job might be executed multiple times.