# How can I access the Rails logger from an initializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, initializer

Following the advice from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059117/where-should-i-put-background-processes-in-rails), I placed my background process in an initializer named scheduler.rb. However, I'm having a hard time getting the newly-scheduled processes to log to the Rails logs. Is there a simple way for me to access the same logs from the initializer, preferably by accessing Rails' default logger methods (logger.info, etc)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info "abc"
```

Answer (score 28):

Rails 3-
Simply use Rails.logger in your initializer

```
Rails.logger.info "blabla"
```

HTH

Comment: Just a quick note about something obvious that I missed for quite a long time. To make this work, you do need to "require 'logger'"

Comment: Works with Rails 4 as well

Answer (score 16):

RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER was deprecated in Rails 3.  The following steps work for me in Rails 3.1.

Set your logger in environment.rb before calling initialize! on your application:

```
Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
MyServer::Application.initialize!
```

Then call the logger in your initializer.

```
Rails.logger.info "Hello, world!"
```